# What are the most solid evidences to prove that the Puranas and Upapuranas have undergone interpolations over time?

Tags: scripture, puranas, interpolation, evidence, upapuranas

What are the most solid evidences to prove that the Puranas and Upapuranas have undergone various accretions, additions, subtractions and interpolations by various individuals over the millennia?

Comment: Refer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58224/29449